# transform header/navigation to navicon while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I would like to create a navigation that minimizes into a 3-bar navigation/navicon on scroll. I did some research to find out the page scroll on a page, but I'm unsure how to change the navigation from inline across the top of the page to a block level links to the far right contained in navicon. Can someone explain how one would do this. would I make two navigations and hide one?

Here is the current js fiddle of the navigation in the default state
http://jsfiddle.net/claireC/8SUmn/

On scroll, I want those 3 links to be contained in a navicon like in the website below
http://goldengridsystem.com

The code below finds out when the user scrolls

```
$(window).scroll (function () {
var topScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (topScroll >= 700) {
     $('header').slideToggle();
    }
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

### 1. Minimized nav indicator

1. Create a minimized nav indicator and hide it.

   ```
   $('<div class="nav-min"></div>').prependTo($('.container')).hide();
   ```
2. Define a click function for `.nav-min`

   ```
   $('.nav-min').click(function () {
       /* To prevent nav being hidden even if 
       scroll Y position is greater than 700 */
       $(this).addClass('expanded');

       /* Show full menu and hide minimized nav indicator */
       $('header').slideDown().removeClass('hidden');
       $('.nav-min').fadeOut();
   });
   ```

### 2. Scroll event

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var topScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (topScroll >= 700) {

            /* Check if minimized nav has been clicked. 
            If it hasn't, hide full nav. */
            if (!$('.nav-min').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $('header').slideUp().addClass('hidden');
                $('.nav-min').fadeIn();
            }

        } else {
            $('header').slideDown().removeClass('hidden');
            $('.nav-min').fadeOut();

            /* Remove "forced-show" method so that  
            it resets back to the initial function */
            if ($('.nav-min').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $('.nav-min').removeClass('expanded');
            }
        }
    })
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/shodaburp/6bAW5/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had this as an idea, but did not get a chance to try on my own yet to see if it would work.

I don't know too much Javascript and I'm a little confused with this code. Where is .expanded and .hidden defined? I searched jQuery API and did not see anything to related.

I also notice that clicking .nav-min gave a small delay and was a little jumpy. If I wanted to make this smoother using CSS, would I remove the fadeOut and define a transition for .nav-min instead?